# Cordova CLI can't find Android SDK using Windows 10

Tags: android, node.js, windows, cordova

I have set my Environment Variables, yet I continue to get the following error:

[Error: Android SDK not found. Make sure that it is installed. If it is not at the default location, set the ANDROID_HOME environment variable.]
ERROR building one of the platforms: Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 2
You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 2
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\oneilj\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\superspawn.js:139:23)
    at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:818:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:211:5)

I have uninstalled Android Studio and all the SDKs, and even un-installed nodeJS and cordova. After re-installing everything I still get the error.

Answer (score 1):

I found this while waiting for an answer. The fix was from another user's question and answer:

Download tools_r25.2.3-windows.zip from Android Downloads.
Extracted zip on desktop
Replaced C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools with extracted sub-folder tools/
In project folder:

$ cordova platforms remove android
$ cordova platforms add android